# can not set title for cell at specific indexPath.row of uicollectionview, UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When working on UICollectionView, I am loading a cell from nib like below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    /* Uncomment this block to use nib-based cells */
    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"NibCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];


    // Configure layout
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    self.collectionView.contentInset    =   UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);

    [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(300, 200)];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
}
```

And my nib file looks like below

[image]

The top label is used to displayed the number of cell and the middle label is used to display a certain text

in method **cellForItemAtIndexPath**, I just want to set the text to the cell of certain row ( in this example, I am doing it at row of 1 ) :

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     // Setup cell identifier
     static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";

     UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
     UILabel *titleLabel    = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
     UILabel *cellLablel    = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:200];
     cellLablel.text         =   self.dataArray[0][indexPath.row];
     if ( indexPath.row == 1)
         [titleLabel setText:@"this is row 1"];

    return cell;

}
```

When running the app, there is a problem on it. Not only is **titleLabel** of cell at **row1** 
set to `This is row 1`, but also the titleLabel of row5 and row9 and row10 is set as well:
[image]

[image]

If anybody knows what I am doing wrong in the middle. please help.

My colleciton is containing 1 section and 15 row for this section.

Comment: have anyone had ideas about this situation ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cells are reused. As soon as you scroll down and Cell 1 gets invisible, the collection view makes it available again. Just set the text for all cells, e.g.

```
titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"this is row %d", indexPath.row];
```

Comment: yeah this is what I did. I have to reset the title